# How i can deploy a website?

Tags: tomcat, server, web-deployment

I have already finished building my website using

> *Java, JSP, Servlet, Tomcat server and MYSQL database*

Everything is working perfectly. But I want my ***localhost:8080/MyProject/...*** become my so dreamed ***www.MyProject.com***

Now I'm worried about one questions that I have no idea:

**-What would be my configuration concerns (regarding tomcat and MySQL)?**

anybody already passed for this situation and could help me with any tip?